# vb.net label won't show session variable

Tags: vb.net

Why does this label show up in my rendered HTML??

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible='<%# false %>' Text='HERE' />
```

I can set the visible to false in the code behind and then it will go away, but what I really want is to set visibility depending on a session variable existing, like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible='<%# isnothing(Session("Login_ID")) %>' Text='THERE' />
```

I could swear I've don't this before, but today it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you aren't telling the `Page` to bind.  Other controls can be bound automatically, such as `DataGrid`s, but you have to tell the page to do it manually.

I think I used to do it like this, somewhere where it made sense (e.g., PreRender lifecycle event):

```
' Me is the Page; call this from the page to bind its controls that use the <%# %> syntax
Me.DataBind()
```

Or, since this is relatively static, use the following in the aspx (equals sign for assignment, rather than # for binding):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Visible='<%= isnothing(Session("Login_ID")) %>' Text='THERE' />
```

Comment: When I do that I get "Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= not isnothing(Session("Login_ID")) %>' for the 'Visible' property."

Comment: Adding the databind() worked. Adding any .databind() for a data control seems to make it work!